# Counting documents based on another table referencing to it

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have these three models:

*Task.js*

```
name: String
```

*Question.js*

```
score: Number,
task_id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Task', alias: 'task' },
problem_id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Problem', alias: 'problem' },
```

*Problem.js*

```
name: String
```

How can I count the number of tasks that matches a certain **task name** and has a question that is connected to a problem that matches a certain **problem id**?